# Show entries that were created after the last logout of an user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I got stuck here...
I have various models in my app with lots of relations, and now I want to display only entries that were created after a user logged out. For this I have  t.datetime "last_active_at" in my users model that get's touched at every logout. This works fine.

I have Projects and Users, Users can be assigned to projects. Projects have documents. I'm showing the User only the documents of the projects he's assigned to. This works.

Now I'd like to show only documents that were created after the user logged out the last time.

What I'd like to do is to compare the created_at timestamp of the ProjectDocument to the last_active_at timestamp of current_user.

user.rb (users itself)

```
  has_many :us_prs
```

project_document.rb (has the documents and projects as references)

```
  belongs_to :project
```

project.rb (projects itself)

```
  has_many :project_documents
  has_many :us_prs
  has_many :users, through: :us_prs
```

us_pr.rb (assigns users (references) to projects (references))

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
```

I have in my controller:

```
    @mynewprojectdocuments = []
      (UsPr.where(user_id: [current_user.id])).each do |mynewprojectdocuments|
      (ProjectDocument.where(project_id: [mynewprojectdocuments.project_id])).each do |pr|  
          @mynewprojectdocuments << pr
       end    
    end
```

my view:

```
<% @mynewprojectdocuments.each do |mynewprojectdocuments| %> 
...
<% end %>
```

I found several posts here that seem to answer similar questions, but I simply don't get it to work.

I want to apologise for any mistakes made here, this is my first question here and I'm not too familiar with how this works, neither am I a real programmer.

I appreciate your help with this!

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you edit your question with the models and the associations please?

Comment: You might want to consider that users hardly ever log out.. :)

Comment: I totally understand why ;) the website helped a lot. Always :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is select all project documents where the project document's project id is within the user's project ids, and created after a certain time?

One of the handy default fields all models tend to have are `created_at`; another one is `updated_at`.  These are filled automagically.

A query to return what you're looking for might be something like this:

```
ProjectDocument.where(project_id: user.projects).where("created_at > ?", User.last_active_at)
```

This assumes two things:

```
ProjectDocument.belongs_to Project
User.has_many Project
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, wow, I'm impressed how fast people react! Thanks a lot!

Comment: hm, this works on it's own, but I can't figure out how to add it to the controller that I posted in the question.

Comment: @Daniel `@documents = Projects.where(...)`, then you can reference `@documents` in your views.

Comment: My answer still stands; you may want to change `User.has_many :us_prs` to `User.has_many :projects, through: :us_prs`, though.